# Atk4 CSS and LESS compiler

Tags: less, atk4, agiletoolkit-css

im trying to play a little with default css of atk4 (4.3.0.dev)

I found some instructions here: https://github.com/atk4/agiletoolkit-css#themes-and-examples

I downloaded [agiletoolkit-css](https://github.com/atk4/agiletoolkit-css#themes-and-examples), as i understand i change agiletoolkit-css-master\framework\less\variables.less (add some atk-swatch-xyz for example).

But when i try to compile agiletoolkit.less from same folder i get error:

```
ParseError: Unrecognised input in ...\agiletoolkit-css-master\framework\less\responsive.less on line 51, column 5:
50 
51 @cs();
52
```

I'm just trying to compile original version. Im using WinLess and SimplLess, same results.

Some guidance would be nice :) Thank you!

Comment: So what are these error messages? (I've tried it with Less 1.7.5 and 2.0.x and it compiles just fine).

Comment: Tried to compile agiletoolkit.less, error: 20:18:02 C:\Users\wechta\Desktop\agiletoolkit-css-master\framework\less\agiletoolkit.less ParseError: Unrecognised input in C:\Users\wechta\Desktop\agiletoolkit-css-master\framework\less\responsive.less on line 51, column 5:
50     
51     @cs();
52

Comment: maybe im just doing something wrong. Just tried to download from https://github.com/atk4/agiletoolkit-css#themes-and-examples, load folder in winless and tried to compile  \agiletoolkit-css-master\framework\less\agiletoolkit.less or framework\css\theme.less. Same error at both.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thus it requires Less 1.7.0 or higher (because of using [this](http://lesscss.org/features/#detached-rulesets-feature) feature). So neither WinLess (which stalled at Less 1.6.x) nor SimpLess (1.3.3?) will compile it. So you will need to use either [`lessc`](http://lesscss.org/#using-less) or find some up-to-date GUI-frontend (Crunch?).

Comment: Aha.. i would never guess it, since im new to less... Crunch also doesn't work, error: Compiler Errors
You are using JavaScript, which has been disabled. (Line: 317)
Filename: mixins.less

Comment: "Compiler Errors You are using JavaScript, which has been disabled. " - :) So I'm afraid it's time for you to get familiar with `node` etc. (Ah, actually I think Brackets with one of it's Less compilation plugins should do it (I'm not sure what version they incude but they update quite often)).

Comment: Yeah, looks like it.. tried https://github.com/leafo/lessphp and also a lot of errors, shame since it would be really nice to compile it on-the-fly.. But really thanx for the help!

Comment: So, if somebody else is reading his, the only working way is lessc. On win install it like this: http://pragmatictim.blogspot.fr/2012/08/developing-with-less-on-windows-getting.html

Comment: @peter, please add you comments as an answer, so i can be accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agile CSS Less code is too advanced to compile it with GUI, i have tried it with several compilers with no success (different errors):
- WinLess
- SimplLess
- Crunch
- lessphp

The only way i succeded was to install node.js with less. Instructions are here: 
http://pragmatictim.blogspot.fr/2012/08/developing-with-less-on-windows-getting.html